# Android application compatible with IMAP search without using local index?

Tags: email, dovecot, imap, android, solr

I use an **email account of several dozens of Giga**, on computer and Smartphone.
However, most applications use a local index to speed up the search of emails (this is the case of Outlook and Thunderbird on computer).
However, on a cell phone, the **memory/battery/performance does not allow to have a correct index** when the mailbox is too big, and the applications are often limited to propose a search on the last weeks.
However, **my IMAP server is compatible with the Full Sring search (via Apache Solr) very quickly**.

**Do you know a mobile application, allowing to deactivate the local search, to make an instant search via IMAP ?**

Comment: Outlook, Gmail, Samsung Email and BlueMail already tested not using IMAP search

Comment: Software and app recommendations should better be posted to  https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com as they are not server related.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to the?

Answer (score 0):

A set of features useful for (mostly: bandwidth and storage) restricted environments is dubbed the ["Lemonade" profile and documented in RFC 5550](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5550). Efficient search without downloading is a major consideration, but do not be too quick to assume it is the *only* feature necessary to make mailing on the go a pleasant experience.

We do not do recommendations here, but afaik there are now multiple clients that implement some or many of the relevant features, and the keywords mentioned in that RFC (title) will help you tailor your search.